# Disable picker video functionality Swift 3

Tags: swift, image, picker

Image picker is working great! However I had like to disable the video option so the user can only take photos?
Any inputs and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lawliet for the input!

Anyone stack at this question, here is what I did.
I removed mediaTypes or comment it out.
When done so, only photos can be taken.
The Apple documentation Lawliet suggested above says this, but indirectly.

Anyway, problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the mediaType to be `kUTTypeImage` only. Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619173-mediatypes) out.

> When you use an image picker controller to capture or choose still
>   images (by including only the  kUTTypeImage  type in the  mediaTypes 
>   array)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.